# Comparing two columns: logical- is value from column 1 also in column 2?

Tags: r, compare, set

I'm pretty confused on how to go about this.  Say I have two columns in a dataframe.  One column a numerical series in order (x), the other specifying some value from the first, or -1 (y).  These are results from a matching experiment, where the goal is to see if multiple photos are taken of the same individual.  In the example below, there 10 photos, but 6 are unique individuals.  In the y column, the corresponding x is reported if there is a match. y is -1 for no match (might as well be NAs).  If there is more than 2 photos per individual, the match # will be the most recent record (photo 1, 5 and 7 are the same individual below). The group is the time period the photo was take (no matches within a group!).  Hopefully I've got this example right:

```
x <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
y <- c(-1,-1,-1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,2,4)
group <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3)
DF <- data.frame(x,y,group)
```

I would like to create a new variable to name the unique individuals, and have a final dataset with a single row per individual (i.e. only have 6 rows instead of 10), that also includes the group information.  I.e. if an individual is in all three groups, there could be a value of "111" or if just in the first and last group it would be "101".  Any tips?

Thanks for asking about the resulting dataset.  I realized my group explanation was bad based on the actual numbers I gave, so I changed the results slightly.  Bonus would also be nice to have, but not critical.

```
name <- c(1,2,3,4,6,8)
group_history <- as.character(c('111','101','100','011','010','001'))
bonus <- as.character(c('1,5,7','2,9','3','4,10','6','8')) 
results_I_want <- data.frame(name,group_history,bonus)
```

My word, more mistakes fixed above...

Comment: Could you add what the result dataset would look like for this example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the (updated) example you gave

```
x <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
y <- c(-1,-1,-1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,3,4)
group <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3)

DF <- data.frame(x,y,group)
```

Use the `x` and `y` to create a mapping from higher numbers to lower numbers that are the same person.  Note that names is a string, despite it be a string of digits.

```
bottom.df <- DF[DF$y==-1,]
mapdown.df <- DF[DF$y!=-1,]
mapdown <- c(mapdown.df$y, bottom.df$x)
names(mapdown) <- c(mapdown.df$x, bottom.df$x)
```

We don't know how many times it might take to get everything down to the lowest number, so have to use a `while` loop.

```
oldx <- DF$x
newx <- mapdown[as.character(oldx)]
while(any(oldx != newx)) {
    oldx = newx
    newx = mapdown[as.character(oldx)]
}
```

The result is the group it belongs to, names by the lowest number of that set.

```
DF$id <- unname(newx)
```

Getting the group membership is harder.  Using `reshape2` to convert this into wide format (one column per group) where the column is "1" if there was something in that one and "0" if not.

```
library("reshape2")

wide <- dcast(DF, id~group, value.var="id", 
              fun.aggregate=function(x){if(length(x)>0){"1"}else{"0"}})
```

Finally, paste these "0"/"1" memberships together to get the grouping variable you described.

```
wide$grouping = apply(wide[,-1], 1, paste, collapse="")
```

The result:

```
> wide
  id 1 2 3 grouping
1  1 1 1 1      111
2  2 1 0 0      100
3  3 1 0 1      101
4  4 0 1 1      011
5  6 0 1 0      010
6  8 0 0 1      001
```

No "bonus" yet.

EDIT:

To get the bonus information, it helps to redo the mapping to keep everything.  If you have a lot of cases, this could be slow.

Replace the `oldx`/`newx` part with:

```
iterx <- matrix(DF$x, ncol=1)
iterx <- cbind(iterx, mapdown[as.character(iterx[,1])])
while(any(iterx[,ncol(iterx)]!=iterx[,ncol(iterx)-1])) {
    iterx <- cbind(iterx, mapdown[as.character(iterx[,ncol(iterx)])])
}

DF$id <- iterx[,ncol(iterx)]
```

To generate the bonus data, then you can use

```
bonus <- tapply(iterx[,1], iterx[,ncol(iterx)], paste, collapse=",")
wide$bonus <- bonus[as.character(wide$id)]
```

Which gives:

```
> wide
  id 1 2 3 grouping bonus
1  1 1 1 1      111 1,5,7
2  2 1 0 0      100     2
3  3 1 0 1      101   3,9
4  4 0 1 1      011  4,10
5  6 0 1 0      010     6
6  8 0 0 1      001     8
```

Note this isn't same as your example output, but I don't think your example output is right (how can you have a `grouping_history` of "000"?)

EDIT:

Now it agrees.

Comment: I just fixed more mistakes :(

Comment: Luckily you figured it out my problem before I even described it correctly.  This is perfect! Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Another solution for bonus variable

```
f_bonus <- function(data=df){
  data_a <- subset(data,y== -1,select=x)
  data_a$pos <- seq(nrow(data_a))
  data_b <- subset(df,y!= -1,select=c(x,y))
  data_b$pos <- match(data_b$y, data_a$x)
  data_t <- rbind(data_a,data_b[-2])
  data_t <- with(data_t,tapply(x,pos,paste,sep="",collapse=","))
  return(data_t)
}
```